# Filter Object based on whether objects contain detail property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object thats returning from an API.

I want to process it easily in Javascript and return only the tests that have a "Grade" property.

The structure of the object looks like this:

```
{
  "ScoreCard": {
    "tests": {
      "test1": {
        "id": 100,
        "score": 0,
        "details": {
          "type": "table"
        }
      },
      "test2": {
        "id": 200,
        "score": 1,
        "details": {
          "type": "Grade"
        }
      },
//moretests
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this with something like Filter?

I know I can get the keys from the Object using

```
var keys = object.keys(response)
```

and if I iterate through that I can create a result set- but it seems very cumbersome.  I am sure there is a simpler solution - that I am not considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method to get each key-value pair and then use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to iterate over the array and generate a combined object.

```js
const data = {
  "ScoreCard": {
    "tests": {
      "test1": {
        "id": 100,
        "score": 0,
        "details": {
          "type": "table"
        }
      },
      "test2": {
        "id": 200,
        "score": 1,
        "details": {
          "type": "Grade"
        }
      },
      //moretests
    }
  }
}
let o;

let res = Object.entries(data.ScoreCard.tests).reduce((obj,  [k, o]) => {
  if (o.details.type === "Grade") obj[k] = o;
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

One-liner solution:

```
let res = Object.entries(data.ScoreCard.tests).reduce((obj, [k, o]) => (o.details.type  === "Grade" && obj[k] = o[k], obj), {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of tests key/values pairs. Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove pairs when their `details.type` is not Grade. Convert back to an object via [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const response = {"ScoreCard":{"tests":{"test1":{"id":100,"score":0,"details":{"type":"table"}},"test2":{"id":200,"score":1,"details":{"type":"Grade"}}}}}

const result = Object.entries(response.ScoreCard.tests)
  .filter(([,v]) => v.details.type === 'Grade')
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({ ...r, [k]: v }), {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the entries and rebuild a new object.

```js
var object = { ScoreCard: { tests: { test1: { id: 100, score: 0, details: { type: "table" } }, test2: { id: 200, score: 1, details: { type: "Grade" } } } } },
    result = Object.assign(...Object
        .entries(object.ScoreCard.tests)
        .filter(({ 1: { details: { type } } }) => type === 'Grade')
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
    );

console.log(result);
```